# Borrowing string works only outside of `match` block

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

I am pretty new to Rust, an I'm currently having an issue with the borrow checker. This code doesn't compile:

```rust
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter) -> fmt::Result {
        let mut out = String::new();
        let mut xs = self.xs.iter();
        for x in 0..11 {
            out += match x {
                3 | 7 => "|",
                _ => &xs.next().unwrap().to_string(),
            };
        }
        write!(f, "{}", out)
    }
```

I get the error

```
error[E0716]: temporary value dropped while borrowed
  --> src/main.rs:32:23
   |
30 |               out += match x {
   |  ____________________-
31 | |                 3 | 7 => "|",
32 | |                 _ => &xs.next().unwrap().to_string(),
   | |                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^-
   | |                       |                            |
   | |                       |                            temporary value is freed at the end of this statement
   | |                       creates a temporary which is freed while still in use
33 | |             };
   | |_____________- borrow later used here
   |
   = note: consider using a `let` binding to create a longer lived value
```

However, this very similar code does compile: (of course, not with the functionality I'm looking for)

```rust
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter) -> fmt::Result {
        let mut out = String::new();
        let mut xs = self.xs.iter();
        for x in 0..11 {
            out += &xs.next().unwrap().to_string();
        }
        write!(f, "{}", out)
    }
```

My question is, why does the first example not work if the second one does? My understanding is that the `match` should just be evaluated as what it's returning, so in the case where `x` is not 3 or 7, it should be functionally the same as the second example.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The arms in a `match` are allowed to be blocks with their own statements.  The impact of that is that temporaries created in a `match` arm are dropped when leaving the arm.  The temporary `String` created by `xs.next().unwrap().to_string()` is thus destroyed before the add-assign can execute, but the arm is attempting to return a borrow against the temporary, resulting in a dangling reference.

The second example you show doesn't have this problem because it doesn't use `match` (or another block construct like `if`) and so the temporary exists until *after* the add-assign is performed.

One way around this is to have both arms of the `match` return a `String`:

```
out += match x {
    3 | 7 => "|".to_string(),
    _     => xs.next().unwrap().to_string(),
};
```

(If you needed the `match` to evaluate as a `&str` you could borrow the result with `&match x { ... }` but that's not necessary here.)

Of course, this adds an extra allocation in the `3 | 7` case, but is required to make the types of the `match` arms consistent.

Consider instead performing the add-assign inside of the `match`.  With this approach, the problem of making the arm types match goes away, and the temporary lifetime issue is also resolved:

```
match x {
    3 | 7 => { out += "|"; }
    _     => { out += xs.next().unwrap().to_string(); }
};
```